# .htaccess write correctly url rewriting page with no suffix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to set the .htaccess

```
ORIGINAL
www.foo.com/bar/index.php?op=find

SHOULD BECOME
www.foo.com/bar/find/
```

I tried in this way but i think there is something wrong because the url does not change

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bar/find/$ /bar/index.php?op=find [L]
```

How can I set it?
Thank you

Comment: "i think there is something wrong" - please describe what's wrong. Are you getting an error, or is the rewrite just not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new rule for redirecting to pretty URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(bar)/index\?op=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(bar)/(find)/?$ /$1/index.php?op=$2 [L,QSA]
```